# Transcribe a code kivy.py to kivy.py - .kv (TextCheckBox)

Tags: python, kivy

I have tried to transcribe a code .py to .py-.kv but have been unsuccessful attempts, the most I achieved was to see the screen and components, but does not perform a basic function that I require. I have searched for several weeks on the Internet and what I find has not served me, I appreciate any support to put the code to work.

The original code is from this website (example of code # 7 "Checkbox List"):

https://www.reddit.com/r/kivy/wiki/snippets#wiki_checkbox_list

It is four "TextCheckBox" with function "on_press" that show in the Widget the selection made:

'Please make selection.'

'You Selected: Software'                 (if you select only one item)

'You Selected: Software, Hardware'            (if you select both Items)

I clarify that the term "active" of the original code, used in .py and .kv, was not accepted by Ninja IDE and I had to change it to the word "on_press".

I only managed to see the Widget, I can make the selection in both TextCheckBox, but the function of showing what is selected is not fulfilled.

Código .py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.factory import Factory

Builder.load_file('ejemplo.kv')


class CheckBoxList(Factory.BoxLayout):
    values = Factory.ListProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._trigger = Clock.create_trigger(self._do_update)
        super(CheckBoxList, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(x=self._trigger, y=self._trigger)

    def add_widget(self, widget, index=0):
        super(CheckBoxList, self).add_widget(widget, index=index)
        widget.bind(on_press=self._trigger)

    def remove_widget(self, widget):
        super(CheckBoxList, self).remove_widget(widget)
        widget.unbind(on_press=self._trigger)

    def _do_update(self, *largs):
        self.values = [tcb.text for tcb in self.children if tcb.on_press]


class TextCheckBox(Factory.ButtonBehavior, Factory.BoxLayout):
    text = Factory.StringProperty()
    on_press = Factory.BooleanProperty(False)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CheckBoxList()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

...........................

código .kv:

```
<CheckBoxList>:

        id: cblist
        TextCheckBox:
                text: 'Software'
        TextCheckBox:
                text: 'Hardware'

        BoxLayout:

                orientation: 'horizontal'
                width: 500
                size_hint: None, None
                pos_hint:{'center_x':.1,'center_y':.50}

                Label:
                        text: cblist.values and 'You Selected: {}'.format( ', '.join(cblist.values)) or 'Please make selection.'

<TextCheckBox>:

        orientation: 'horizontal'
        on_press: cb.on_press
        on_press: root.on_press= not root.on_press
        CheckBox:
                id: cb
                on_press: root.on_press
        Label:
                id: lbl
                text: root.text
```

The expected results are that the .py-.kv code shows the selection made from one or both of the TextCheckBox options.

Comment: You might want to translate the title into English as well.

Comment: @chepner, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody answers my question yet but I'm still advancing in my project, as I mentioned before, I modified the code to use more the .kv file, now I have the main screen and the secondary screens.

The project is about a yearbook with 12 months and every month with 30 days, the idea is that the user has a global vision of the follow up of his activity for a year in a single view.

In the screen "main", each button of the calendar represents a day (365 buttons) and each button directs towards another screen (1, 2, 3, ..., 365) where there are four "CheckBox" that show the activities are identified with the letters (R, F, C, T), which can be selected individually or in group in any order and any quantity, for example: R, RC, RFT, RFCT.

We also have three buttons (Accept, Clean, Return); with "Accept" I send internally the "CheckBox" selected to the screen "main" and then with the button "Return" I return to "main" and I can see the data of my selection made; with the button "Clean" I can delete the selection made previously and when I press the button "Back", I would find that day without any data, completely clean, and if I want I can enter again and make a different selection.

What is missing is that the selection made and that I already have in the main screen or in "main", I can save it in a backup so that when I close the application the data will not be erased, so that when I open it again, they will be there on each of the days that I have selected during the time of use of the application.

On the other hand, it is missing that in the days the selected options the letters have the color according to each selection of the checkboxes.

Next I share the codes .py and .kv that I have realized and that I already commented to them, in order that you can verify it in your PC's in case somebody wants to find a possible solution; I must indicate that the code next, is in a minimum expression of only one month (January) and only four days (1, 2, 3, 4), since all the complete year is a lot of code to publish directly here in this WebSite.

Before I show you the minimized code, I leave you images of what it looks like when you have the whole year to get an idea of the project:

[Screen "main" with 365 buttons, that is, 365 days, of which only the first four are directed to the second screen, for the minimized example that I expose.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFDcw.jpg)

[Screen "1" with the four options to select, you can see the buttons " Aceptar ", " Limpiar " and " Volver ".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TT57U.jpg)

[Screen "1" with the four options selected and other three examples.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBUYa.jpg)

[Screen "main" with the selections made shown on days 1, 2, 3 and 4.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy6tc.jpg)

Thank you very much.

I used kivy ver. 1.11.1

Code .py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox

Builder.load_file('anuario Ver minima.kv')

class Anuario(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Anuario, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def reset_checkbox_1(self):
        for child in reversed(self.ids.grid_1.children):
            if isinstance(child, CheckBox):
                child.active = False

    def limpiar_1(self, text):
        self.ids['button_1'].text = ""
        self.gender1 = ''
        self.gender2 = ''
        self.gender3 = ''
        self.gender4 = ''

    def reset_checkbox_2(self):
        for child in reversed(self.ids.grid_2.children):
            if isinstance(child, CheckBox):
                child.active = False

    def limpiar_2(self, text):
        self.ids['button_2'].text = ""
        self.gender5 = ''
        self.gender6 = ''
        self.gender7 = ''
        self.gender8 = ''

    def reset_checkbox_3(self):
        for child in reversed(self.ids.grid_3.children):
            if isinstance(child, CheckBox):
                child.active = False

    def limpiar_3(self, text):
        self.ids['button_3'].text = ""
        self.gender9 = ''
        self.gender10 = ''
        self.gender11 = ''
        self.gender12 = ''

    def reset_checkbox_4(self):
        for child in reversed(self.ids.grid_4.children):
            if isinstance(child, CheckBox):
                child.active = False

    def limpiar_4(self, text):
        self.ids['button_4'].text = ""
        self.gender13 = ''
        self.gender14 = ''
        self.gender15 = ''
        self.gender16 = ''

    gender1 = StringProperty("")
    gender2 = StringProperty("")
    gender3 = StringProperty("")
    gender4 = StringProperty("")
    gender5 = StringProperty("")
    gender6 = StringProperty("")
    gender7 = StringProperty("")
    gender8 = StringProperty("")
    gender9 = StringProperty("")
    gender10 = StringProperty("")
    gender11 = StringProperty("")
    gender12 = StringProperty("")
    gender13 = StringProperty("")
    gender14 = StringProperty("")
    gender15 = StringProperty("")
    gender16 = StringProperty("")

    def insert_data(self):

        self.ids['button_1'].text = format(self.gender1)+(self.gender2)+(self.gender3)+(self.gender4)
        self.ids['button_2'].text = format(self.gender5)+(self.gender6)+(self.gender7)+(self.gender8)
        self.ids['button_3'].text = format(self.gender9)+(self.gender10)+(self.gender11)+(self.gender12)
        self.ids['button_4'].text = format(self.gender13)+(self.gender14)+(self.gender15)+(self.gender16)


class MyAppApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Anuario()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyAppApp().run()
```

Code .kv

```
<Anuario>:

    ScreenManager:
        id: manager
        size_hint: 1, .9999

        Screen:
            name: 'main'

            BoxLayout:
                padding: 1
                spacing: 1
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: 0.075, 0.947   #ancho y alto bloque meses
                pos_hint:{'center_x':.04,'y':.00} #alineación izquierda bloque meses
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 1, 0, 0
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos

                Button:
                    text:"Enero"
                    font_size:15
                    halign:'left'
                    color:1,.5,0,1

            BoxLayout:

                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 0, 1, 0
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos

                orientation: "horizontal"
                size_hint: 0.92, 0.05 #ancho y alto bloque encabezado 31 días
                pos_hint:{'center_x':.540,'y':.95} #alineación izquierda bloque encabezado 31 días

                Button:
                    text:"1"
                    font_size:20
                    size_hint: .12, 0.99
                    halign:'left'
                    color:1,.5,0,1
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':.06,'y':.01}

                Button:
                    text:"2"
                    font_size:20
                    size_hint: .12, 0.99
                    halign:'left'
                    color:1,.5,0,1
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':.06,'y':.01}

                Button:
                    text:"3"
                    font_size:20
                    size_hint: .12, 0.99
                    halign:'left'
                    color:1,.5,0,1
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':.06,'y':.01}
                Button:
                    text:"4"
                    font_size:20
                    size_hint: .12, 0.99
                    halign:'left'
                    color:1,.5,0,1
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':.06,'y':.01}

            BoxLayout:
                padding: 1
                spacing: 1
                orientation: "vertical"
                size_hint: 0.92, 0.948 #ancho y alto bloque días
                pos_hint:{'center_x':.540,'y':0.0} #alineación izquierda bloque días
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 0, 0, 1
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos

                GridLayout:

                    size:self.size
                    rows: 12
                    cols: 31
                    Button:
                        id: button_1
                        text: ""
                        font_size:14
                        on_press: root.ids.manager.current = '1'
                    Button:
                        id: button_2
                        text: ""
                        font_size:14
                        on_press: root.ids.manager.current = '2'
                    Button:
                        id: button_3
                        text: ""
                        font_size:14
                        on_press: root.ids.manager.current = '3'
                    Button:
                        id: button_4
                        text: ""
                        font_size:14
                        on_press: root.ids.manager.current = '4'

        Screen:
            name: '1'
            on_leave: root.reset_checkbox_1()
            BoxLayout:
                padding: 1
                spacing: 1
                orientation: "vertical"
                size_hint: 0.55, 0.55   #ancho y alto screen de seleción
                pos_hint:{'center_x':.50,'y':.30} #alineación izquierda screen de seleción
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 0, 0, .2 #color fondo del screen de selección
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos

                GridLayout:
                    id: grid_1
                    size:self.size
                    cols: 2
                    size_hint:.9, .99
                    padding : 100,20
                    spacing: 20, 20
                    row_default_height: '10dp'

                    Label:
                        text: "R"
                        color:1,0,0,1
                        text_size: self.size
                        halign:'center'
                        valign: 'middle'
                    CheckBox:
                        id : chk
                        text: "R"
                        on_active:
                            root.gender1 = self.text

                    Label:
                        text: 'F'
                        color:1,1,0,1
                        text_size: self.size
                        halign:'center'
                        valign: 'middle'
                    CheckBox:
                        text: "F"
                        on_active:
                            root.gender2 = self.text

                    Label:
                        text: 'C'
                        color:0,1,0,1
                        text_size: self.size
                        halign:'center'
                        valign: 'middle'
                    CheckBox:
                        text: "C"
                        on_active:
                            root.gender3 = self.text

                    Label:
                        text: 'T'
                        color:0,0,1,1
                        text_size: self.size
                        halign:'center'
                        valign: 'middle'
                    CheckBox:
                        text: "T"
                        on_active:
                            root.gender4 = self.text

                    Button:
                        id: Button1_Aceptar
                        text: 'Aceptar'
                        on_press: root.insert_data()
                    Button:
                        id: Button1_Limpiar
                        text: 'Limpiar'
                        on_press: root.limpiar_1(button_1.text)

                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: "vertical"

                        Button:
                            size_hint: 1.5, 0.99
                            pos_hint:{'center_x':1.06,'y':.00}
                            text: 'Volver'
                            on_press: root.ids.manager.current = 'main'

        Screen:
            name: '2'
            on_leave: root.reset_checkbox_2()
            BoxLayout:
                padding: 1
                spacing: 1
                orientation: "vertical"
                size_hint: 0.55, 0.55   #ancho y alto screen de seleción
                pos_hint:{'center_x':.50,'y':.30} #alineación izquierda screen de seleción
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 0, 0, .2 #color fondo del screen de selección
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos

                GridLayout:
                    id: grid_2
                    size:self.size
                    cols: 2
                    size_hint:.9, .99
                    padding : 100,20
                    spacing: 20, 20
                    row_default_height: '10dp'

                    Label:
                        text: "R"
                        color:1,0,0,1
                        text_size: self.size
                        halign:'center'
                        valign: 'middle'
                    CheckBox:
                        id : chk
                        text: "R"
                        on_active:
                            root.gender5 = self.text

                    Label:
                        text: 'F'
                        color:1,1,0,1
                        text_size: self.size
                        halign:'center'
                        valign: 'middle'
                    CheckBox:
                        text: "F"
                        on_active:
                            root.gender6 = self.text

                    Label:
                        text: 'C'
                        color:0,1,0,1
                        text_size: self.size
                        halign:'center'
                        valign: 'middle'
                    CheckBox:
                        text: "C"
                        on_active:
                            root.gender7 = self.text

                    Label:
                        text: 'T'
                        color:0,0,1,1
                        text_size: self.size
                        halign:'center'
                        valign: 'middle'
                    CheckBox:
                        text: "T"
                        on_active:
                            root.gender8 = self.text

                    Button:
                        id: Button2_Aceptar
                        text: 'Aceptar'
                        on_press: root.insert_data()
                    Button:
                        id: Button2_Limpiar
                        text: 'Limpiar'
                        on_press: root.limpiar_2(button_2.text)

                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: "vertical"

                        Button:
                            size_hint: 1.5, 0.99
                            pos_hint:{'center_x':1.06,'y':.00}
                            text: 'Volver'
                            on_press: root.ids.manager.current = 'main'

        Screen:
            name: '3'
            on_leave: root.reset_checkbox_3()
            BoxLayout:
                padding: 1
                spacing: 1
                orientation: "vertical"
                size_hint: 0.55, 0.55   #ancho y alto screen de seleción
                pos_hint:{'center_x':.50,'y':.30} #alineación izquierda screen de seleción
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 0, 0, .2 #color fondo del screen de selección
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos

                GridLayout:
                    id: grid_3
                    size:self.size
                    cols: 2
                    size_hint:.9, .99
                    padding : 100,20
                    spacing: 20, 20
                    row_default_height: '10dp'

                    Label:
                        text: "R"
                        color:1,0,0,1
                        text_size: self.size
                        halign:'center'
                        valign: 'middle'
                    CheckBox:
                        id : chk
                        text: "R"
                        on_active:
                            root.gender9 = self.text

                    Label:
                        text: 'F'
                        color:1,1,0,1
                        text_size: self.size
                        halign:'center'
                        valign: 'middle'
                    CheckBox:
                        text: "F"
                        on_active:
                            root.gender10 = self.text

                    Label:
                        text: 'C'
                        color:0,1,0,1
                        text_size: self.size
                        halign:'center'
                        valign: 'middle'
                    CheckBox:
                        text: "C"
                        on_active:
                            root.gender11 = self.text

                    Label:
                        text: 'T'
                        color:0,0,1,1
                        text_size: self.size
                        halign:'center'
                        valign: 'middle'
                    CheckBox:
                        text: "T"
                        on_active:
                            root.gender12 = self.text

                    Button:
                        id: Button3_Aceptar
                        text: 'Aceptar'
                        on_press: root.insert_data()
                    Button:
                        id: Button3_Limpiar
                        text: 'Limpiar'
                        on_press: root.limpiar_3(button_3.text)

                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: "vertical"

                        Button:
                            size_hint: 1.5, 0.99
                            pos_hint:{'center_x':1.06,'y':.00}
                            text: 'Volver'
                            on_press: root.ids.manager.current = 'main'

        Screen:
            name: '4'
            on_leave: root.reset_checkbox_4()
            BoxLayout:
                padding: 1
                spacing: 1
                orientation: "vertical"
                size_hint: 0.55, 0.55   #ancho y alto screen de seleción
                pos_hint:{'center_x':.50,'y':.30} #alineación izquierda screen de seleción
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 0, 0, .2 #color fondo del screen de selección
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos

                GridLayout:
                    id: grid_4
                    size:self.size
                    cols: 2
                    size_hint:.9, .99
                    padding : 100,20
                    spacing: 20, 20
                    row_default_height: '10dp'

                    Label:
                        text: "R"
                        color:1,0,0,1
                        text_size: self.size
                        halign:'center'
                        valign: 'middle'
                    CheckBox:
                        id : chk
                        text: "R"
                        on_active:
                            root.gender13 = self.text

                    Label:
                        text: 'F'
                        color:1,1,0,1
                        text_size: self.size
                        halign:'center'
                        valign: 'middle'
                    CheckBox:
                        text: "F"
                        on_active:
                            root.gender14 = self.text

                    Label:
                        text: 'C'
                        color:0,1,0,1
                        text_size: self.size
                        halign:'center'
                        valign: 'middle'
                    CheckBox:
                        text: "C"
                        on_active:
                            root.gender15 = self.text

                    Label:
                        text: 'T'
                        color:0,0,1,1
                        text_size: self.size
                        halign:'center'
                        valign: 'middle'
                    CheckBox:
                        text: "T"
                        on_active:
                            root.gender16 = self.text

                    Button:
                        id: Button4_Aceptar
                        text: 'Aceptar'
                        on_press: root.insert_data()
                    Button:
                        id: Button4_Limpiar
                        text: 'Limpiar'
                        on_press: root.limpiar_4(button_4.text)

                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: "vertical"

                        Button:
                            size_hint: 1.5, 0.99
                            pos_hint:{'center_x':1.06,'y':.00}
                            text: 'Volver'
                            on_press: root.ids.manager.current = 'main'
```